# How do I join animations to create a multi-take animation?

Tags: animation

I have a single fbx that contains multiple animations. They are in a sequence, separated by times only.
Here is a screenshot from within Unity:

[image]

I would like to use them on a different model in Unity. Using the "Humanoid" retargetting is not an option because the hands are not mapped correctly.

I have found out that there is a new Add-On for Blender named "[Rokoko](https://www.rokoko.com/)".
It allows to retarget animations.
It's simple: You load a source and a target, then you click "Retarget".

The first problem that I experienced was that Blender wouldn't import all animations. There is a [bug in Blender (it exists since ages and still does to present)](https://developer.blender.org/T78899) which causes to only import the very first animation.

The only workaround that I found was to split the big fbx into hundreds of small single-animation fbx files using Autodesk FBX converter.

I can then import all these single animations in Blender, they looks like this:

[image]

Rokoko however requires that animation source / target are in the same pose.
Had Blender imported the FBX with the many animations correctly, I could simply pose the first frame and be done.

But I have over 100 single animations, and it is impossible for me to pose over 100 animations so that the first frame shows the same pose.

How could I solve this problem? Could I join these animations again within Blender?
Or does anybody have a different idea?

I believe that if Rokoko would include the option to load a bind pose (instead of the 1st frame being in the same position), it would solve my problem, but I don't know if Rokoko would create such an option. But I think it would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Philipp from Rokoko. I gave this a try and the animations get imported correctly. Are you sure you are accessing them at the right place? Here is how to find them: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8v9y.gif

Also using a bind pose is an interesting idea, I will look into that. But it's very likely not going to be part of this release version.

Comment: Thank you. Now that you have seen the many animations in sequence. Can you please recommend how to batch-process them in Blender with Rokoko? I think Rokoko can only process 1 animation at a time, right?

Comment: Well currently you can't batch process them with the Rokoko plugin. But if you edit the rest position of the target armature to be the same as the source armatures rest position, you can go through the animations pretty quickly and retarget them one by one. You just have to select the next animation to retarget in the source armature after each retargeting process.

Also note that the retargeted animations get added to the list of animations, so be careful what you select there. The new animations have "Retarget" at the end of their name.